# Implementar Lista Ligada dentro de Template Lista Ligada

Tags: c++

Tengo una template de Lista Doblemente Ligada y Nodo. Quiero implementar un objeto del tipo ListaLigada dentro de la estructura a partir de la que creo la Lista Ligada principal. El problema que tengo es que no termino de comprender cómo acceder a la lista interna.

Mi Nodo recibe una estructura para crear los nodos que van dentro de la Lista Ligada; así que quiero acceder a una Lista Ligada que estará dentro de la estructura principal. No tengo ni idea de cómo hacer esto, estoy muy perdida.

Anexo mi template de LL y la declaración de mi estructura.

[image: Estructura]

Y después solo asigné memoria dentro de mi void main(). Por favor, necesito ayuda.

Template:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef LL
#define ll

template <class T1> struct Nodo {
public:
    T1 info;
    Nodo* prev;
    Nodo* next;
    Nodo(){ }
    Nodo(T1 data)
    {
        this->info = info;
    }
    ~Nodo() {}
};

template <class T> class ListaLigada
{
public:
    T* head=NULL, *tail=NULL;
    ListaLigada();
    void AddNodo(T nodo);
};

template <class T> void ListaLigada<T>::AddNodo(T nodo)
{
    T* aux = NULL;
    aux = new T(nodo);
    aux->next = NULL;
    aux->prev = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = aux;
        tail = aux;
    }

    else
    {
        tail->next = aux;
        aux->prev = tail;
        tail = aux;
    }

}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes serios problemas de diseño, concepto e implementación en tu código.

- El [*include guard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) está mal y no funcionará: compruebas sobre `LL`, pero defines `ll`.

  - Además añades el `#pragma once`, que es el *include guard* del compilador C++ de Microsoft, por lo que no es estándar ni portable.
- Tu nodo es una estructura y lo primero que haces es definir la zona pública de dicha estructura, esto es redundante: las estructuras son públicas por defecto.
- El constructor por defecto no tiene cuerpo, podrías haber usado el definido por el compilador usando `default`, lo mismo para el destructor.
- El constructor con parámetro recibe un argumento del tipo del argumento de plantilla, pero no lo usas, en cambio igualas la variable `Nodo::info` sobre si misma.
- Parametrizas tu lista asumiendo que el argumento de plantilla será siempre un nodo, si te instancian tu plantilla con un tipo que no sea tu nodo, el código fallará por todos lados.

  - Esto quita el sentido de una lista de datos, la gracia es poder parametrizar con datos arbitrarios.
- La estructura `Alumno` almacena un puntero a lista, esto es propenso a errores, usa una instancia.
- La estructura `Alumno` almacena datos de texto como formaciones de caracteres; esa aproximación es propia de C, en C++ se suele usar `std::string`.

Para acceder a la lista dentro de `Alumno`, basta con usar el operador punto (`.`):

```
Alumno a;
a.materias_alumno->AddNodo(/* lo que corresponda */);
```

Pero esto sería con el código como lo tienes ahora, que no es ni correcto ni adecuado, mi propuesta es la siguiente:

```
template <class T> class ListaLigada
{
    // El nodo debe ser privado e inaccesible desde fuera.
    // No es necesario que sea plantilla, porque usa los datos plantilla de la clase madre.
    struct Nodo {
        T dato;
        Nodo* prev = nullptr;
        Nodo* next = nullptr;
        Nodo() = default; // Deja que el compilador te haga el constructor.
        Nodo(T1 data) : dato{data}
        //              ^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Usa la lista de inicialización del constructor.
        {
        }
        ~Nodo() = default; // Deja que el compilador te haga el destructor.
    };
    // Los datos, deben ser internos e inaccesibles desde fuera.
    Nodo* head=NULL, *tail=NULL;
public:
    ListaLigada() = default;
    void AddDato(T dato)
    {
        // Hacer cosas...
    }
};
```

También propongo cambiar `Alumno`:

```
struct Alumno
{
    // Todos los miembros son públicos por defecto.
    std::string id;
    std::string nombre;
    std::string carrera;
    // materias_Alumno es redundante, la lista ya está dentro de 'Alumno'.
    ListaLigada<Materia> materias;
};
```

Con el código anterior, puedes añadir `Materia`s de la siguiente manera:

```
Alumno a;
a.materias.AddDato({/* argumentos de construcción de 'Materia' */});
```